# Are there denormalized floats that evaluate to the same value apart from +0/-0?

Tags: hash, floating-point, 64-bit, ieee-754, floating-point-conversion

**Hashing floats**
I want to feel floats (singles, doubles etc) to a hash function.
I want the hash function to generate the same hashes for things which are really the same, but have a different binary representation.

Thus +0/-0 should be normalized.
The many NaN's should be merged into a single representation.
Same for +Inf (which is different from -Inf), etc.

**Question**
Apart from +0/-0, are there denormalized floats, which really translate to the same discrete value, or can I just hash their binary representation as is, without fear of generating different hashes for identical values?

**Bonus question:** if there are, what is the fastest way to convalescence these denormals into a unique representation other than using `frexp`?
(Answer preferably in X64 SSE2 assembly, however C is also OK).

For performance reasons I want to do as little prep work as possible before feeding my floats to the hash. I don't care about compatibility.

Comment: Note that in IEEE754 there isn't a single NaN... There are "many" NaN. In a 32 bit float there are like 24 bits of possible payload for a NaN (1 bit of sign and 23 bits of payload)

Comment: Other than the problem of NaN and +-0, all the values of a IEEE754 float are distinct and if converted to a uint32_t/uint64_t t, if the endianness is the same, strictly ordered

Comment: For your bonus question, a language should be written... Given your reference of *frexp*, you probably mean C.

Comment: @xanatos No, x64 assembly actually.

Comment: If you use NaN as a key in a hashtable based on IEEE 754 equality, you are probably doing something wrong. Anyway, the hash of NaN doesn't matter, since NaN != NaN. You can use different hashes for different NaNs, you can use different hashes for “the same” NaN, the hash function is still compatible with IEEE 754 equality.

Comment: You can add zero to your number to normalize -0, but I'm not really sure what else you want, the NaN thing doesn't really make sense to me, the infinity thing doesn't either (there have only one representation anyway)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Apart from +0/-0, are there denormalized floats, which really translate to the same discrete value, or can I just hash their binary representation as is, without fear of generating different hashes for identical values?

There is no translation from the representation to something else that would be the “real” value. There is only IEEE 754 equality, which is an equivalence relation but makes some values with differing representations equal. +0.0 and -0.0 are the only floating-point values with differing representations that are equal.

You don't need to do anything special with the many representations of NaN, all NaNs are different (for IEEE 754 equality), even when they have the same representation. Thus NaNs do not need to have the same hash. The same representation of NaN doesn't even need to have the same hash as itself.

Comment: Having a value hash to different things at different times might break invariants of the hash table.

Comment: @tmyklebu I would say that it's having keys that are not equal to themselves that's breaking invariants of the hash table.